# Why is my print preview blank using window.print?

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to print my view and its data using window.print but when i click on my print button the preview is blank instead of showing my datatable and all its content. I just get a blank page with my title and the localhost url

This is my simple js function:

```
<script>
  function ImprimirPagina(){
    window.print('');
  }
</script>
```

And this is my blade view:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Main row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Left col -->
            <section class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
                <div class="card" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="font-weight-light text-white">Productos
                            <a class="btn bg-white float-right btn-sm" href="{{ route('products.add') }}"><i
                                    class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar Producto</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>

                    
                </div><!-- /.card-header -->
                <div>
                    
                    
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                        <thead class="thead">

                            

                            <tr>
                                <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Moneda de Compra</th>                                                                       
                                <th>Costo Fob</th>
                                <th>Moneda de Venta</th>
                                <th>Precio de Lista</th>
                                <th>Margen Bruto</th>
                                
                                <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           
                            @foreach($file as $key => $product)
                            @if($product->status == 1)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>                                    
                                    <td>{{ $product->costUSD }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->sale_coin}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->list_priceUSD}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marginUSD}}</td>
                                    
                                    @php
                                    $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
                                    @endphp
                                        <td>


                                        <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                            href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                                        <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                                            style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                                            href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                            href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{route('products.detail', $product->id)}}" ><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></a>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif

                                
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.card-body -->

                <button onclick="ImprimirPagina();" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
                
        </div>
```

This is the print button:

```
<button onclick="ImprimirPagina();" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
```

And this is what my print preview looks like:

[image]

Comment: And what do you see when you _actually_ try to print, using the browser's print option, and  you look at the preview?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think that _is_ the browser's print preview

Comment: [Window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) accepts zero parameters so why are you passing it an empty string?

Comment: Do you have any CSS media queries with `@media print`? Try [forcing print-preview mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/print-preview/) in your dev tools so you can inspect what's being applied

Comment: @phil yes, but JS triggered. I meant "what happens when you hit ctrl/cmd-P".

Comment: @Phil i tried wihout passing any parameter and i got the same result. I passed the empty string because afterwards i saw a tutorial of the ussage of window.print and the guy passed an empty string.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you mean before clicking on the button? i have a data table. And its weird because i have two pages of data in my data table using pagination and if i try to print that it appears both pages blank. But if i filter something in the search field as you can see in the top right of the image it recognizes the filter and appears to be just one page because the amount of rows where reduced while passing somenthing to the search field.